# Invalid Grant error after being redirected to client application from OpenIdDict application

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an application using OpenIdDict Beta 6 with ASP.NET Core 5.

I am using OpenIdDict Velusia sample and I have the following client:

```
 OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor application = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor {
   ClientId = "spa",
   ClientSecret = "secret",
   ConsentType = OpenIddictConstants.ConsentTypes.Implicit,
   PostLogoutRedirectUris = {
     new Uri("https://localhost:5002/oidc/signout")
   },
   RedirectUris = {
     new Uri("https://localhost:5002/oidc/signin"),
   },
   Permissions = {
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,             
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Email,
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
     OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "api"
   },
   Requirements = {
     OpenIddictConstants.Requirements.Features.ProofKeyForCodeExchange
   }
 };
```

On my client application I am using [OIDC Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) and I have the following settings:

```
const settings: UserManagerSettings = {
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  authority: "https://localhost:5000",
  client_id: 'spa',
  client_secret: "secret",
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,
  post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5000/oidc/signout",
  redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5000/oidc/signin",
  response_mode: 'query',
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email api'
};
```

I am able to login with email/password and to logout ...

When I login with Google I am redirected back to OpenIdDict application.

I get the successful login message and asked to confirm email to create the account.

I confirm it and I get redirected back to the spa client application ...

But when the OIDCClient-JS, in the spa, calls "/connect/token" I get the error:

```
Error: invalid_grant
```

It was working with previous OpenIdDict version ...

What am I missing?

Comment: Your question is not actionable: you don't include any error description or log messages. It's just impossible to guess what's the root cause.

Comment: I though the problem was only in my configuration that why I didn't extend the explanation. In your `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method you are creating the `var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };`. Then on Exchange method you have `await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user)` which fails if `RequireConfirmedEmail` is set to `true` in Identity Options. Don't you think that Email should be set as verified when the login is made with an External Provider since most providers (Google, Facebook, ...) already verity emails?

Comment: It's certainly something you can do. The code you're referring to was part of the default VS ASP.NET Core 1.0 templates, so it's not something I've written myself. Feel free to tweak that or switch to Identity UI.